# 『Pythonではじめる機械学習』の mglearn を使いたいが、not defined となる

Tags: python, 機械学習, github

今オライリー・ジャパンの「Pythonではじめる機械学習」という本で機械学習の勉強を始めています。そこで、GitHubにあるmglearnというライブラリを入手したいのですが、やり方が分からず困っています。Download ZIPというボタンを押して保存したりしているのですが、うまくいきません。できるだけ詳しく教えていただけると助かります。mglearnのリンク先は下です。
https://github.com/amueller/introduction_to_ml_with_python

回答ありがとうございます。説明が足りなかったので、もっと詳しく書きます。自分が使いたいコードが入っているのはmglearnというファイルです。しかし、上のリンク先には他にimagesや01-introduction.ipynbなども入っています。mglearnのみダウンロードすることは可能ですか。DownloadZIPを押すと全てダウンロードされます。そして、「X, y = mglearn.datasets.make_forge()」というコードをjupyter notebookで打つと「name 'mglearn' is not defined」という表示が出てきます。

Comment: 「うまくいきません」と言うことですが、どのようにうまくいかないのか、具体的に説明していただいた方が、より適切な回答をより早く得ることにつながります。ご自身の環境(Windows?, Mac?, Linux?そのバージョンは?)や、「したりしている」が具体的に何をどうしたのか(箇条書きで順序を追って簡潔に)、「うまくいかない」と言うのはそもそも何が起こっているのか(ダウンロード自体ができない?ダウンロードされた.zipの解凍方法がわからない?ダウンロードも解凍もできたが使い方がわからない?指示通りに使って見たがxxxなんてエラーが出る?…) まずはそれらを詳しく説明することが、できるだけ詳しい回答を得ることにつながります。ご自身の質問は「編集」できるはずなので、現在のご質問の下に追記してみてください。

Comment: Windows 7 + Firefoxの環境で試してみましたが「Download ZIP」での保存、および保存したZIPファイルの解凍は特に問題ありませんでした(アーカイバはCubeICEを使用、7-zipでのテストも問題無し)。

Comment: @my way いくつかの点で認識違いがあるようです。 / 1) リンク先に"mglearn"というファイルはありません、これはディレクトリ(フォルダ)名になります。 / 2) GitHubから単一のファイルをダウンロードすることも可能ですが、今回必要としているのは「ライブラリ」なので、ファイル一式を入手・インストールしないと正しく動作しないと思います。 / 上記を踏まえて、リンク先にも記載がありますが、`pip install mglearn`でインストールする方法もあるようなので確認してみてください。

Comment: 回答ありがとうございます。リンク先にあった通りに、jupyter notebookに!pip install mglearnと打ち込むとインストールができました。しかし、その後にjupyter notebookにX, y = mglearn.datasets.make_forge()と打つと同じようにname~の表示が出てきました。インストールした後に何かしらの操作をしなければいけないのでしょうか。

Comment: ライブラリを実際に使用する際は、事前に(名前空間を)インポートする必要があります。`import mglearn` / インポートせずにmglearnを使おうとすると、「そんな名前はどこにも定義されていない」とエラーで怒られているわけです。

Comment: @my way 回答に書いておきました

Comment: ありがとうございます。できました！本当に助かりました。

Answer (score 4, accepted):

簡単に結論をいえば、jupyter notebook（それ以外の場合も同じです）で`mglearn`を使う場合には、`!pip install mglearn`でインストールして（勿論できていれば必要はないですが）、`import mglearn`でインポートする必要があります。

ただし、`mglearn`をインポートする方法としては、`import mglearn`と明示的にする以外に別の方法があり、「Pythonではじめる機械学習」では、その別の方法を使っています。

02-supervised-learning のコードは以下のようになっています。これだけをみるとJupyter Notebookで `X, y = mglearn.datasets.make_forge()`と打ち込むと動作するように思うかもしれません。

```
%matplotlib inline
from preamble import *

# generate dataset
X, y = mglearn.datasets.make_forge()
```

しかし、`preamble.py`のコードは以下のようになっています。

```
from IPython.display import set_matplotlib_formats, display
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import mglearn

中略

__all__ = ['np', 'mglearn', 'display', 'plt', 'pd']
```

`from preamble import *`とすることで、`__all__`にあるモジュールがインポートされます。`from preamble import *`という書き方は、処理に時間がかかったり、副作用がおこったりするので嫌われていますが、`__all__`でされるインポートされるモジュールで明示することでその問題は解決できます。ドキュメント [パッケージから * を import する](https://docs.python.jp/3/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package)

また、`*`を使うと可読性に乏しいコードになるため使用を避けるべきとなっており、この質問でも混乱がおこっていますが、チュートリアルにあるように対話セッションでキータイプの量を減らすために使うのは有効な使い方です。チュートリアル [6.1. モジュールについてもうすこし](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/tutorial/modules.html#more-on-modules)

Jupyter Notebookで`mglearn`を使う場合には、`pandas`,`numpy`,`matplotlib`等も使うはずで、それを毎回入力するのは手間なので、`preamble.py`をカレントディレクトリにコピーして`from preamble import *`とすることで入力の手間を省くことができます。また、ファイルのコピーが手間な場合は、`preamble.py`の中身をコピーしてJupyter Notebook のセルにペーストして実行することでも対応できます。

また、https://github.com/amueller/introduction_to_ml_with_python からダウンロードして、それのJupyter Notebookのファイル（.ipynb）を使う場合は、`mglearn`をインストールする必要はありません。なぜかというと`mglearn`のソースコードがそこに入っているためです。それ以外の場所で使う場合は、`mglearn`を`pip`でインストールする必要があります。